# Macro crashes while creating pivot out of large data sets

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite new to VBA and excel macros but want to automate certain reports for work and I am really hoping for someone's help. I tried to fix it myself by watching YouTube videos and reading stackoverflow but the solution didn't match with my issue. For now I created few macros but i am stuck with the one which should actually create a pivot table.

I first created a regular table out of the data I had (using TableP Macro beloew). It looks like it works fine (tested few other data sheets) :

```
Sub tableP()
'
' tableP Macro (Creates a table of the existing data sheet, regardless the data input)
'

    ActiveCell.Cells.Select
    ActiveCell.Activate
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$1:$1048576"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table2"
    ActiveCell.Cells.Select       `
`End Sub   `
```

The second macro (below) would ideally take that table (an object) and create a pivot table, however it crashes **(excel stops working while I run the macro)** each time I use a bigger dataset.

```
   Sub Macro1test() '
' Macro1test creates dataset out of the existing table
'      
    Dim dataname As String
    Dim Newsheet As String
    dataname = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name
        Sheets.Add
    Newsheet = ActiveSheet.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            dataname, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
            :=Newsheet & "!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:= _
            xlPivotTableVersion14
        Sheets.Select
        Cells(3, 1).Select
    End Sub
```

Can please someone let me know what am I doing wrong and what steps am missing to be able to apply those macros on any data set?

Comment: Do you actually need to include 17,179,869,184 cells in the calculations?

Comment: Are you referring to the List Object  Range within the first macro? I know it's an exaggeration but not sure how to make the range "dynamic" rather then specifying it.

Comment: `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` will refer to your whole dataset, provided it contains no blank rows/columns

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1test()
' Macro1test creates dataset out of the existing table
'
Dim dataname As String
Dim RngStr As String
Dim Newsheet As String
Dim NewSht As Worksheet

Dim PvtCache As PivotCache
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable

' set the Range String for the Pivot Cache Source Data)
RngStr = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)

' add a new sheet
Set NewSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)

' set the Pivot Cache object
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=RngStr)

' set the New Pivot Table object
Set PvtTbl = NewSht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=NewSht.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai, thank you! I am getting an error on this line  
RngStr = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)

Comment: @Klaudia do you have your `LostObject` (table) in the `ActiveSheet` ?

Comment: Hi Shai, apologies, was convinced that this approach was without a table. As you can see i am a complete beginner. It works now and I am extremely happy with your help!

Comment: @Klaudia you're welcome :) now comes your part where you mark as "ANSWER" by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer (it will turn green)

Comment: Learnt something new today :)